# concatenate content of tables in new table with + does not work what else do I have to use?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the code that is in my book:

```
select CategoryName + Description as together
from categories;
```

This should give me a bunch of rows with CategoryNameDescription content glued to one another in the same cell.

This does not happen. the result is always 0.

What do I have to use to make this concatenate?

I use SQL workbench.

Comment: Ok so Concat() does the job but why on earth does my book say I need to use + and rtrim?

Comment: What type are these fields?